# tell mysql to ignore updates/inserts for auto increment values

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

Is there a way to tell mysql to ignore any tentative to assign any value to an auto-increment column?. We are using slick and it seems to try to assign the value of 0 to any auto-increment column at the time a new row is created. These auto-increment columns are not primary keys.

Comment: You need to give a more concrete example here, like a query you're actually running or code that produces the query. If your column cannot be null and is set to `AUTO_INCREMENT` then it will automatically get a value if you haven't provided one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a **before insert** trigger, you should be able to do something like `SET NEW.id = NULLIF(NEW.id, 0);`. Of course, this means nothing can ever insert 0 into the field without dropping the trigger first. (Though update queries still can still set it to 0).

Comment: what could be the trigger  'before update' to assign NEW.id the same value it has before the update? In this way I could avoid the update with the new value?

Comment: I think `SET NEW.id = IF(NEW.id = 0, OLD.id, NEW.id);` to only prevent it from being changed to 0, or `SET NEW.id = OLD.id;` to prevent id from ever being changed. _(Not 100% sure, but if you have updating cascades on foreign keys this might cause issues.)_

Comment: the field is not for foreign key and I need to preserve the first value it got doesn't matter if someone executes an update on it.